# Export Firestore sub-collection to CSV or JSON locally

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, export

I'm in a bit of a pickle. Any help is appreciated.

I'm fairly new to Firebase and done so much Googling but I can't seem to get this working.

I have a sub-collection with 100k+ documents and I need to export these locally, ideally in CSV format so we can manage the data.

I've followed tutorials and tried the Firebase Export to a Cloud bucket, but it seems to results are encrypted and I'm not sure how to use them? No tutorial explains this.

I've tried just querying with admin-sdk but the query times out, same with cloud functions even with 2GB memory limit.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't provide an export tool for CSV, so you will need to make queries and write the way you need.  If you have a large collection, you'll want to apply [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to get everything without timing out or running out of memory.  You can run the code on your desktop - no need to go through Cloud Functions.

Comment: Ahh pagination, thank you I will give this a try. At this point I'm happy to run it locally I just need a way to export the data. Thank you.